# Interpret the characteristic function of $A\backslash B$ in terms of $f_A$ and $f_B$.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

- Interpret the characteristic function of $A\backslash B$ in terms of $f_A$ and $f_B$.

[Recall](https://www.wikizero.com/en/Characteristic_function)

My solution: Let $x\in A\backslash B$. It means that $x\not\in B$ and $x\in A$. Hence, we get, $f_A(x)=1$ and $f_B(x)=0$.

**Can you check my solution?**

Comment: You didn't offer a solution. You were supposed to give a formula for $f_{A\setminus B}$ in terms of $f_A$ and $f_B$. Hint: multiplication.

Comment: @ziggurism Multiplication? How can I do it?

Comment: For example, for what values of $x$ is $f_A(x)f_B(x)$ equal to $1$?

Comment: @if $x\in A$ and $x\in B$ then we get your claim, i.e., it is equal to 1. But, why we do multiplicaition?

Comment: Why multiplication? Because of the fundamental property (in an integral domain) that $ab=0\rightarrow a=0\vee b=0.$ Multiplication can encode boolean operators. You have now checked the $f_{A\cap B}=f_Af_B.$ what about $f_{A\setminus B}$?

Answer (score 0):

If $f_A$ and $f_B$ are the characteristic functions of sets $A$ and $B$, then we can see by checking that $f_{A\cap B}=f_A\cdot f_B,$ and $f_{B^c}=1-f_B.$ Putting the two formulas together, we see that $f_{A\setminus B} = f_{A\cap B^c} = f_A\cdot(1-f_B).$